# Why doesn't IF statement provide result?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[I use the =IF statement in Excel but the value in the cell doesn't change at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtOfM.png)
[image]

Comment: Your question should contain the full details to be answerable without using external links - external links, including pictures, should be supplementary only.

Answer (score 5):

You have an apostrophe before the equals sign ('), so Excel treats the cell's contents as text, and not a formula.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know it might have been very stupid but before it wouldn't change it :(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your System Settings (Thanks @Excel Hero), your might have to separate parameters in formulas with `;` instead of `,`:

```
=IF(A1>50000;"too expensive";"let's buy it")
```

That (and @Travo's answer regarding the leading `'`) should solve your problem.

Comment: That's system dependent

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Oh, really? I didn't know that. Depending on the operating system, the language settings or what?

Comment: No. Most users of Excel use the comma to separate function arguments. However, this is a system setting. I AM TEMPTED to downvote this answer. You should remove it.

Comment: Since my the mixup between `;` and `,` may still be the reason his (or someone else's stumbling across this) formula isn't working (in addition to the `'`), I edited my answer accordingly instead of deleting it.